# SPARK dataframe error: cannot be cast to scala.Function2 while using a UDF to split strings in column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I keep getting a error when I use udf to split string in a column by a delimiter. I am using Scala

```
Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1 cannot be cast to scala.Function2
```

Don't know what this is and how to fix it.

This is my udf and data frame:

```
val rsplit = udf((refsplit: String) => refsplit.split(":"))


+---------+--------------------+--------------------+
|     user|              jsites|             jsites1|
+---------+--------------------+--------------------+
|123ashish|m.mangahere.co:m....|m.mangahere.co:m....|
|456ashish|m.mangahere2.co:m...|m.mangahere2.co:m...|
|   ashish|m.mangahere.co:m....|m.mangahere.co:m....|
+---------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

the column jsites look like `m.manghere.co:m.facebook.com:.msn.com`. And I am trying to use the udf to split `m.manghere.co:m.facebook.com:.msn.com` by `:`.

I keep getting that error

Comment: Which code actually gives that error? When creating the UDF or when using the UDF? If the latter, how do you use the UDF?

Comment: while using the udf. `ff.withColumn("split sites",rsplit(ff.col("jsites1")))`

Comment: Can you provide a minimal, complete, verifiable example? Those two lines plus some guessing what you have before and after doesn't give any problem to me, with a full example we can maybe actually reproduce it and find the cause. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. It can also help to provide spark version used, and check you are using the same version as on your cluster. Same for Scala, that you're not using 2.11 with Spark for 2.10.

Comment: Have you tried using the built-in UDF that splits strings? See https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#split(org.apache.spark.sql.Column,%20java.lang.String).

Comment: Another thing to try is to use the `split` overload that takes a single character (i.e. `refsplit.split(':')`). This might be a problem with the return type of the UDF being a Java array instead of a Scala array.

Comment: @PermaFrost that worked. Thanks and thanks all !

Answer (score 4):

this type of error indicates that when you used the `udf`, the parameter lists are not matching. e.g. you try to pass 2 parameters to the udf, while udf only accepts 1

Answer (score -1):

there s a split function provided in `org.apache.spark.sql.functions`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col,split}

val df = ???
df.withColumn("split sites",split(col("COLNAME"), "REGEX"))
```

The questions kind of old, hope this helps someone else. Cheers